# desktop application on Chrome

Tags: javascript, desktop

I have a basic knowledge of html, css and javascript, enough to build some simple web sites.

What I need now is to create a simple desktop application (bookmarks manager), running on Chrome, win7 64bit.

Is it possible without learning a new language and please for some short steps?

Comment: Google chrome itself have a bookmark manager plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik?hl=en. Please check it is that what you need. Then simple add it and use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a desktop application based on chrome engine your choice is [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). It's certainly the best option available now. It offers:

- Great docs
- Many examples and code snippets
- Very broad and helping open-source community
- All desktop app features fully packed in one beautiful engine
- Only javascript/html/css knowlege needed
  ...And much more

You'll probably want to start with the [Docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/) with many great guides inside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! All you need is the knowledge of Html, Css and JavaScript (possibly jQuery for UI) and a basic understanding of Json files.

I hope this link gives you everything that you are looking for. I started  from here when I wanted to build a chrome extension:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Their Getting started tutorial is very helpful.

Comment: If I understand - you say I need to create a Chrome extension ?

Comment: yes for managing bookmarks on chrome, chrome extensions are great! You can even create similar add-ons for firefox, but thats a different story.

Answer (score 1):

You could either develop a Chrome Extension or an actual desktop app using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/).